# What's the purpose of nb_epoch in Keras's fit_generator?

Tags: neural-network, keras, training-data

It seems like I could get the exact same result by making num_samples bigger and keeping nb_epoch=1. I thought the purpose of multiple epochs was to iterate over the same data multiple times, but Keras doesn't reinstantiate the generator at the end of each epoch. It just keeps going. For example training this autoencoder:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import (Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, 
    UpSampling2D, Activation)
from keras.models import Sequential

rand_imgs = [np.random.rand(1, 100, 100, 3) for _ in range(1000)]

def keras_generator():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print(i)
        rand_img = rand_imgs[i]
        i += 1
        yield (rand_img, rand_img)


layers = ([
    Convolution2D(20, 5, 5, border_mode='same', 
        input_shape=(100, 100, 3), activation='relu'),

    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same'),

    Convolution2D(3, 5, 5, border_mode='same', activation='relu'),

    UpSampling2D((2, 2)),

    Convolution2D(3, 5, 5, border_mode='same', activation='relu')])

autoencoder = Sequential()
for layer in layers:
    autoencoder.add(layer)

gen = keras_generator()
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
history = autoencoder.fit_generator(gen, samples_per_epoch=100, nb_epoch=2)
```

It seems like I get the same result with (samples_per_epoch=100, nb_epoch=2) as I do for (samples_per_epoch=200, nb_epoch=1). Am I using fit_generator as intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - you are right that when using `keras.fit_generator` these two approaches are equivalent. But - there are variety of reasons why keeping `epochs` is reasonable:

1. **Logging:** in this case `epoch` comprises the amount of data after which you want to log some important statistics about training (like e.g. time or loss at the end of the epoch).
2. **Keeping directory structure** when you are using generator to load data from your hard disk - in this case - when you know how many files you have in your directory - you may adjust the `batch_size` and `nb_epoch` to such values that epoch would comprise going through every example in your dataset.
3. **Keeping the structure of data when using `flow` generator** - in this case, when you have e.g. a set of pictures loaded to your `Python` and you want to use `Keras.ImageDataGenerator` to apply different kind of data transformations, setting `batch_size` and `nb_epoch` in such way that epoch comprises going through every example in your dataset might help you in keeping track of a progress of your trainning process.